# Updating Node.JS app and restarting server automatically

Tags: node.js

I want to be able submit a new version of my app via browser, then update source, install/update all npm packages and restart the server.

Right now I do it via post request. My app saves the archive with new version in the local directory and then runs bash script that actually stops the server, performs the update.

The problem is that server stops before it gets response. I use forever to run my node app.

The question: is there any standard way to update the app? Is it possible to do it without server restart?

Answer (score 0):

hahahah wow omg this is just out there in so many ways. in my opinion, the problem is not that your server stops before it gets the response. it's that you aren't attacking the problem from the right angle. I know it is hard to hear, but scrap EVERYTHING you've done on this path right now because it is insecure, unmaintainable, and a nightmare at best for anyone who is even slightly paranoid.

Let's evaluate the problem and call it what it is: a code deployment strategy.

That said, this is a TERRIBLE deployment strategy. Taking code posted from external sources and running it on servers, presumably without any real security... are you for real?

Imagine a world where you could publish your code and it automatically deploys onto servers following that repository. Sounds sort of like what you want, right? Guess what!?! It exists already! AND without the middleman http post of code from who knows where. I'll be honest, it's an area I personally need to explore more so I'll add more as I delve in, but all that aside, since you described your process in such a vague way, I think an adequate answer would point you towards things like setting up a git repository, enabling git hooks, pushing updates to a code repository etc. To that effect, I offer you these 4 (and eventually more) links:

http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/
https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa
https://readwrite.com/2013/09/30/understanding-github-a-journey-for-beginners-part-1/
https://readwrite.com/2013/10/02/github-for-beginners-part-2/

Per your comment on this answer... ok. I still stand by what I've said though, so you've been warned! :) Now, to continue on your issue.

Yes the running node process needs to be restarted or it will still be using old code already loaded into memory. Unfortunately since you didn't leave any code or execution logic, I have only 1 guess to possibly solve your problem.

You're saying the server stops before you get the response. Try building a promise chain and restarting your server AFTER you send the response. Something like this, for ExpressJS as an example:

```
postCallback(req, res, next) {
  // handle all your code deployment, npm install etc.
  return res.json(true) // or whatever you want response to contain
    .then(() => restartServer());
}
```

You might need to watch out for `res.end()`. I can't recall if it ends all execution or just the response itself. Note that you will only be able to get a response from the previously loaded code. Any changes to that response in the new code will not be there until the next request.

Comment: I understand all the security problems of this model, but I do it just for the sake of the experiment. And I have already have working script that pulls the code from github and deploys it. The problem is that I don't want to run my scripts from the server manually. I want to launch them from the browser

Answer (score 0):

Wow.. how about something like the plain old exec?

```
const { exec } = require('child_process'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
})); 
app.post('/exec', function(req, res) {
    exec(req.body.cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    });
});
```

(Oviouvsly I'm joking)